# How is my/the user's web browser displaying a web page built in Perl?

Tags: perl, web

this isn't a specific programming related question, but more so a conceptual/software engineering related question.

I'm a new web dev hire at a small local company, who was given a really cool chance to learn and grow as a professional. They were kind enough to give me a chance, and I'd like to be proactive in learning as much about how their back-end system is working as I can, considering it's what I'll be working in most of the time.

From what I've gathered, their entire in-house built job tracking interface is built in Perl (will the aid of css, js, and sql), where the html pages are generated and spat out as the user wants to access them.

For example, if I want to access a specific job, it'll look like this in the user's url.  `https://tracking.ourcompanywebsite/jobtracker/job/1234`

On the internal side, I know we have a "viewing" script that would be called something like "JobView" that will literally query all of the fields in the perl script, and structure an html page around that data we are requesting.

My question is, how the fudge is this happening? How does a user putting in that address on the url trigger a perl script to run on our server, and generate a page that is spat back out to the user?

I guess that's my main curiosity. In your average bare bones web development courses in college, I learned to make your html, css, and js files. When you want to view a web page, you simply put the directory of that html page, and it constructs everything around that.

When you put a directory to a perl file in a browser, it will just open that raw perl code haha.

I'm sure there may be some modules and various add-ons in our software that allows this to all work, that I may be missing, so please forgive me.

I know you guys don't have the codebase in front of you, but I figured conceptually there is something to be learned that doesn't necessarily need all of the specifics.

I hope that this question could be used for any other amateur devs having the same questions.

Comment: Web server receives request, looks at its configuration to see what it should do with it. If configuration says "send a file", it sends a file. If it says "run some perl", it runs some perl.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following two snippets:

```sh
cat file | program
```

```sh
printf 'foo\n' | cat | program
```

In the first snippet, `cat` reads its output from a file. In the second, it gets it from another program. But `program` doesn't care about any of that. It just reads whatever was provided to its STDIN.

The web browser is like `program`. It doesn't care where the web server got the HTML or image or whatever it requested. It sends a URL, and it receives a response with a document from the web server.

The web server, like `cat`, can obtain what it needs from multiple sources. Specifically, it can be configured to get the requested document in a few different ways.

The "default" would be to map the URL to a directory and return the file found there. But that's not the only option. There are two other major options commonly found in web servers:

[**Common Gateway Interface (CGI)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface)

Some web servers can be configured to run a program based on the URL received. Information about the request is passed to the program, which is tasked with producing a response. The web server simply returns the output of this program to requesting browser.

[**FastCGI**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI)

It can be quite wasteful to spawn a new child for each request. FastCGI allows a web server to talk to an existing persistent process or pool of processes that listen for requests from the webserver. Again, the web server simply returns the response from this request to the requesting browser.